# Is there any difference between ThisActivityName.this.finish() and finish()

Tags: java, android, scope

Is there a difference between these two?

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();

startActivity(intent);
ThisActivityName.this.finish();
```

**Note:** `ThisActivityName` is the name of the activity the code is in. I'm being told to perform `ThisActivityName.this.finish();` instead of just `finish()` when starting a new activity. So I'm curious to if there is any difference. In a scenario where I'm just starting the next Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple answer

There's no difference *usually*.

### Longer rant

They are calling **the same method**, however, calling it like `ThisActivityName.this.finish();` ensures that in the unlikely event that wherever you are executing the code happens to also have a `finish` method, you'll call the right one. Even in the scenario you're mentioning where you're calling `startActivity` first, that doesn't remove the possibility of calling the wrong method, specially with a common name such as `finish`.

Say you are inside a custom class inside your activity file, that has a finish method declared, that also happens to take no arguments. Calling `finish()` will call that method instead of the activity one.

### Sample code

```
public class WadusActivity extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }
    public class SomeOtherClass{
        public SomeOtherClass(){
            WadusActivity.this.finish(); //This calls the activity finish
            finish(); //This calls the method below
        }
        public void finish(){
            //method also named finish
        }
    }
}
```

Unlikely? Yes. Impossible? Not at all.

The basic need we have is to understand what `this` refers to in each situation. When `this` is used as-is, it will refer to the first wrapping class instance containing the keyword, if we want to reference something higher in the hierarchy, we will need to prepend the class name, like you are doing with `ThisActivityName.this`

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference, they are the same.

Comment: Not always true, though